# What are the differences between the FireOS Kindle App and the Android Kindle App?

Tags: kindle, publishing, kindle-app, android, kindle-fire

I've recently been working on an ebook that I intend to self-publish.  I was testing it using the Kindle Previewer application on my Mac, but when I tested the book on actual iOS devices (iPad and iPhone), I realized there were many problems that I had to fix.

So, I want to test on an Android device too, but I don't own one at present.  I was thinking of buying a FireHD because it's a cheap tablet and I will only use this to test my book, but I know FireOS and Android are originally based off the same code but not exactly the same.

My question is: **Are the FireOS Kindle and Android Kindle apps similar enough that I can test on one and be reasonably sure that my book will display about the same on the other?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, the Kindle apps on both stock Android and FireOS are very similar. So you should have no bother with how your ebook is displayed within the application on those operating systems.

**One additional point to add** - You can get an Android emulator on your PC/Laptop and test out your ebook within the Kindle app on this emulated version of android.
The link below shows off several Android emulators that you can pick from, have a read and see if any of those options are helpful to you :)

https://www.androidauthority.com/best-android-emulators-for-pc-655308/

Comment: My bad - added the link there :)